# Fragment with SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android

I've got an app with left navigation drawer, switching between different fragments. Inside one of those fragment I want to implement `SlidingTabLayout`.

So, what I did is I copied the `SlidingTabLayout.java` and `SlidingTabStrip.java` from Google's `iosched` app. I used them inside my fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <mynamespace.widget.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_tabs"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_pager"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And then in my Fragment class, inside onCreateView method, I instantiated my pager and SlidingTabLayout like this:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment_pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new HomePagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment_tabs);
        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
```

And this is my FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private String[] tabs = { "Today", "This week", "With star" };
        private Fragment[] tabFragments = {
                new TodayTabFragment(),
                new WeekTabFragment(),
                new StarTabFragment()
        };

        public HomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i)
        {
            return tabFragments[i];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            return tabs[position];
        }
    }
```

Also I got separate Fragment class and layout for each tab, which is nothing special. And it works, but as soon as I switch to other fragment with my navigation drawer, when I get back, content of one of tabs just dissapears. Mostly it happens to second tab. Also, if I select the `HomeFragment` from navigation drawer, when is already displayed, I get a nullpointerexception inside `SlidingTabLayout.java` at this line: `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);`

Any way of fixing it? I have no idea what to do. I guess my code would work, but inside activity. Possible to make it work inside fragment?

Comment: Can you give a piece of source code of activity that changes fragments? Don't set adapters in onCreateView, set it in onActivityCreated ...

Comment: `@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
    {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, fragments[position])
                .commit();
    }`

Comment: i think you should create always a new object of fragment (not use old instances-fragments[position] ). Because when you create new instance you are guaranteed that all fragment lifecycles (onCreate, onCreateView, onActivityCreated etc) will be called (and therefore new instance of HomePagerAdapter will be created)...

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. Please use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter which will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

What I did is instead of implementing FragmentPagerAdapter, I implemented PagerAdapter then I overriden the instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) method and destroyItem() method.

Link, that helped me: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic/SlidingTabsBasicFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change constructor of `HomePagerAdapter` to:

```
public HomePagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager fm)
{
    super(fm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you begin transaction instead of suuportfragmanager change it to childfragmentmanager